# How do I upload Excel file with time values to Datazen Publisher?

Tags: excel

I keep getting the following error code (translated from danish):

"The value was either too large or too small for an Int32".

I have tried all data/time formats and all that include time fail.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with Windows 10 running Datazen Publisher for Windows 7. Solved with Publisher for Windows 8+.